# Tools to create Rails schemas and relations visually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a tool which can be used to quickly create sample schema structures, that can be then used as a reference while coding.

I know [railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady), creates schema/model visualization from existing rails app, but are there any tools to create these schema and relations by hand.

Thanks.

Comment: how you mean by hand? but as I know ,there is http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/ which can generate erd

Comment: To me it sounds like he wants to go the other way:  from a diagram to a schema.

Comment: @Nich As Jesper mentioned. I want to create a diagram for reference for later coding.